# Redirect output at libc level

Tags: python, redirect

I want to redirect output in such a way that works for output generated by C modules that print directly to stdout. The standard approach doesn't work here:

```
sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'w')
```

because this doesn't operate at the libc level.

The function freopen() can do this, but how can I access this from python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file with `os.open` and the appropriate options (`os.O_WRONLY` etc.) and afterwards do a `os.dup2(<new fd>, 1)`.